# How to remove shaking from overflow css animation?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm currently doing a React app which shows what music I'm listening at that time. Obviously some of song names, album name etc. are longer than others so I want to show overflowing part with animation. I managed to do this and it's kinda okay. Longer text scrolls nicely but my problem is it also animates short texts and that causes some shaking on them during the animation.

Any ideas how to remove that shaking? Also Javascript based solutions are appreciated but this seemed to be shorter solution.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div p {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  
  animation: 5s linear 0s infinite alternate scrolltext;
}

@keyframes scrolltext {
  0%,
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    left: 0%;
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a very long text and rolls nicely</p>
  <p>And these</p>
  <p>two shaking?!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The seems to be that the `translateX` has a higher resolution than `left`. IMO the simplest solution would be if you could do `transform: translateX(-100%) translateX(100px)` and get rid of the `left`

Comment: @Thomas you found the real culprit and the best solution: Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Kaiido Because I don't know how viable the solution is, as it relies on knowing the available width in an absolute measurement like `px` or `rem` and so it doesn't play well with many responsive layouts. And I'm still playing around with two other approaches, besides other things.

Comment: Oh good point I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use margin-left and margin-right instead of left and right

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div p {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  
  animation: 5s linear 0s infinite alternate scrolltext;
}

@keyframes scrolltext {
  0%,
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a very long text and rolls nicely</p>
  <p>And these</p>
  <p>two shaking?!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This fixes the problem. Thanks buddy!